# Is there any way to read the properties of a Compressed Archive?

Tags: compression, zip

Are there any tool / simple method to read the properties (Ex : Compression level, Dictionary size, word size etc)?

Comment: To answer your question: yes, there are many such tools. Anything specific?

Comment: I just want to get properties for reference. I don't need to get it programatically. I want to use an existing archive, extract it, make some changes, recompress it and use with a program.

Comment: Um... If you aren't asking how to do this programatically... then why are you asking on a programming site?

Comment: Need more info in the question.  In addition to the questions above, you didn't mention which sort of compressed archive. gzip?  .zip?  .rar?  any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the properties of a .Zip archive, you can try my [Zip-Parser](http://github.com/alanhaggai/Zip-Parser/tree/master). It is written in Perl and you may have to install some modules.

Remember to comment out `'Compressed Data'` in `zip_parser.conf` by prepending with a `#`, else you will be printing lots of compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

To uncompress, modify, recompress, `zip` and `unzip` should be all you need on any Unix platform.  On Windows I'm not up to date, but at one time the best version was PKZIP (but you may have to pay for that).  Certainly cygwin should include zip and unzip; I don't know about mingw.

Answer (score 0):

In [python](http://www.python.org), the [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) and [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) modules provide support for gzipped/bzipped tar files and zip files respectively save for multi-disk zipfiles, which are not yet supported.